# Linear modelling question and answer book

Tags: references

The book [McCune (2013)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/McGraw-Hills-500-Statistics-Questions/dp/0071798722/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=500+statistics+questions&qid=1608898624&sr=8-1) gives 500 question and answers on introductory statistics.

Are there any books out there which give questions and answers specifically on linear models (simple linear regression, multiple regression, logistic regression etc)?

---

McCune, Sandra K. *McGraw-Hill's 500 statistics questions: ace your college exams.* McGraw-Hill Education, 2013.

Comment: [Here's a textbook](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Econometrics-Edition-Addison-Wesley-Economics/dp/0138009007) some classes use.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you mean to look for books with answers right in the same book. If that is not the case, I would go for Wooldridge's “[Introductory Econometrics: A Modern Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1337558869)”; there is a separate solution manual. A number of data sets are provided online, in various formats. I love it.